# Trading VWAP VBA

Tags: vba

I am having some problems with a VBA function, it works perfectly for values less than 5000, but when I give a large amount of data, like 10.000 the function simply returns an error in excel. Do you know why? Here it is the code:

```
Function VWAP(Prices As Variant, Volume As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Prices.Rows.Count
ReDim Z(n, 1)

Dim result As Double
Dim Lots As Integer
Lots = 0
result = 0

For i = 1 To n
    Z(i, 1) = (Prices(i, 1) * Volume(i, 1))
    Lots = Lots + Volume(i, 1)
    result = result + Z(i, 1)
Next i

VWAP = result / Lots

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you use an integer for Lots
Just `Dim Lots as Long` and it won't overflow